# Magento 2 - include JS library without Require.JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, pdf

I'm trying to include the jsPDF library in my Magento 2 like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("Vendor_Module::js/jsPDF.js"); ?>"></script>

     <div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>A paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>


    <script>
    require(['jquery','jquery/ui'], function($){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                $('#cmd').click(function () {
                    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    });
                    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                });
        });
        </script>
```

The error message it returns is this:

```
require.min.js:16 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){"use strict";function se(t){return(se="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t)
```

Consequently the library doesn't work for me.
How can I properly include this JS library without using Require.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:-

open link copy and past in jsPDF.js

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js

Replace phtml file:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl("Vander_Module::js/jsPDF.js"); ?>"></script>
    <div id="content">
    <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>


<script>
    require(['jquery','jquery/ui'], function($){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Man thanks for the answer, i tested your code but the issue remains. Please check my question again because i updated my code of test.

Comment: I updated the code, please check.

Comment: issue your jsPDF.js file.

Comment: I tested your code but again not work. Issue remains. I use jQuery 1.12.4 and this version of jsPDF: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js

Comment: share your jsPDF.js file

Comment: I copied and pasted jsPDF.js from the link I put you. I didn't do anything else. I can't share full file because there is too much code. I have not made any other changes

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118959/discussion-between-himanshu-and-jackom).

Comment: uploaded my jsPDF.js  file in chat, please check https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118959/discussion-between-himanshu-and-jackom

Comment: Updated code please check, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118959/discussion-between-himanshu-and-jackom